# MySQL calculate percentage of online vs phone orders for each customer

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL DB with three tables `Customer`, `Order`, and `OrderType` where the order type is online or phone.

I need to calculate the percentage of orders of each customer by order type.

```
CUSTOMER
id
name

ORDER
id
customer_id
ordertype_id

ORDERTYPE
id
name
```

Ideally, the results would have:

```
CUSTOMER   |    ONLINE     |    PHONE
name             20%             80%
name             45%             55%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select o.customer_id,
       100 * avg( ot.name = 'ONLINE' ) as online_percent,
       100 * avg( ot.name = 'PHONE' ) as phone_percent
from orders o join
     ordertype ot
     on o.ordertype_id = ot.id
group by o.customer_id;
```

You can add an addition `join` if you want the customer name instead of the id.

Comment: Thanks! I have added the additional join and I now have what I needed. Your time and help is much appreciated!